# Php ssh - Error starting up SSH connection(-1)

Tags: php, ssh, debian, remote-access, libssh2

I  want to connect to another server by ssh using PHP but i get error as below .i looked for it very much but couldn't find any suitable solution for me.

> Warning: ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-1): Failed sending banner in ...
>   Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to ...

this is my php code :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($details[0]['address'], $details[0]['port']);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $details[0]['username'], $details[0]['password']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to diagnose issues with libssh2 is nigh impossible. My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html), and assuming that doesn't resolve the issue you can get logs that'll assist in the diagnosis. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');

echo $ssh->getLog();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.That's a nice php lib, but i wanted to know more about that problem and its occurance time.can you help me on that ?